# Re-apply filter when needed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have written my own simple translation filter:

```
angular.module('app')
    .filter('translate', translate);

translate.$inject = ['translation', 'language'];

function translate(translation, language) {

    return function(value) {
        var result = translation[language.getLanguage()][value];


        if (!result) {
            throw new Error("no translation");
        }

        return result;

    }

}
```

The language can change: after logging in, the user might use a different language than the default one.

However, the filter doesn't re-apply: the old translation is still displayed. Is there a way to execute the filter again when the language changes?

In this case, the dependency 'language' is a service which contains the language. getLanguage() returns this language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're taking an interesting but flawed approach for this. Angular filters are **reapplied only when the value being filtered is changed**, so they aren't suited for actually changing the inputs themselves. You could do this employing a stateful filter though, which is a feature added in Angular 1.3.

You only need to set the $stateful property to true in your filter and make sure to inject a dependency. This way, angular will refresh the filter when necessary.

Here's an example based on your code.

```
filter('translate', ['translation', 'language', function (translation, language) {
    function translationFilter(value) {
        var result = translation[language.getLanguage()][value];
        if (!result) {
            throw new Error("no translation");
        }
        return result;
    }

    translationFilter.$stateful = true;    
    return translationFilter;
}]);
```

Note that stateful filters may reduce performance, so you can take a different approach if this gives you trouble.

The better solution would be using [angular-translate](https://angular-translate.github.io/), which not only handles all of this for you in a more mantainable way, but also offers a (stateful) filter doing the exact thing you want to do.

Take a look at [this](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/api/pascalprecht.translate.filter:translate) API, for example.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the information. I'm now using a stateful filter, which works fine. I'll have a look at the translate module and see if it has some advantages I can use in my project.